# GWT Application gets "404 The requested resource is not available"

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I do not know why I keep getting "404 The requested resource is not available", when I am accessing my GWT Application. I am hosting my GWT application, on my TomEE/8.5.6 (7.0.2) at home, currently.

Here is the situation.

1. I am able to use my GWT application from "TomEE Web Application Manager" as (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index
2. However, when I type (http)://www.zethanath.tk in the browser, I would get (https)://www.zethanath.tk/ with HTTP Status 404.

Here is the details of my configuration.

```
Ubuntu:/opt/tomcat/webapps$ ls -l
total 20932
drwxrwxr-x 14 tomcat tomcat     4096 Aug  4 11:46 docs
drwxrwxr-x  5 tomcat tomcat     4096 Aug  4 11:46 host-manager
drwxrwxrwx  5 tomcat tomcat     4096 Aug 25 08:46 Index
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat 21411520 Aug 25 08:46 Index.war
drwxrwxr-x  5 tomcat tomcat     4096 Aug  4 11:46 manager
drwxrwxr-x  3 tomcat tomcat     4096 Aug  8 17:30 ROOT
```

sudo nano 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >  
   Protocols h2 http/1.1
   ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
   ServerName  www.zethanath.tk
   ServerAlias servlet.zethanath.tk zethanath.tk

   DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat/webapps/Index"

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.zethanath.tk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

sudo nano default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
      Protocols h2 http/1.1

      ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
      ServerName  www.zethanath.tk
      ServerAlias servlet.zethanath.tk zethanath.tk

      DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat/webapps/Index"

      JKMountCopy On
      JKMount /* ajp13_worker

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      SSLEngine on

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

      <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      </FilesMatch>
      <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      </Directory>

      </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I keep thinking that I need to associate port 8080 with "DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat/webapps/Index", but I am unsure how.

Here is the details of my UFW. I have similar setup in the router.

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
990/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Secure              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache Secure (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Uoo, you really should NOT use DocumentRoot or you will be exposing the whole war.

You better use mod_proxy to redirect request to the tomcat http port:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Or if you want to redirect to a tomcat context (ex. 'Index'):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/Index/ retry=1
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/Index/
Header edit Location ^([^/]*//[^/]*)?/Index/(.*)$ $1/$2
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /Index /
```

More info here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Comment: if you are not sure about what I mean with "expose the whole war" just open http://localhost/WEB-INF/web.xml with your current configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Also, is there any way we can stick to Mod JK? I heard Mod JK is better, so I made a switch from Mod Proxy to Mod JK. I can't switch back again :)

Comment: Please also note that I did the Mod_rewrite in the end of http vhost. This piece would redirect the users to SSL vhost and SSL vhost would redirect the users to GWT application using Mod JK.

Comment: I will check out web.xml now as well. There might be something in there?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply. Here is the content of my /opt/tomcat/conf/web.xml. Please notice that my GWT application is stored in /opt/tomcat/wepapps/ with the name **Index.war**, so I keep thinking that I might not need to configure "welcome-file-list" near the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>development</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>abs</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ai</extension>
        <mime-type>application/postscript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>aif</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-aiff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>aifc</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-aiff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>aiff</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-aiff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>aim</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-aim</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>art</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-jg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>asf</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-ms-asf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>asx</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-ms-asf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>au</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/basic</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>avi</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-msvideo</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>avx</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-rad-screenplay</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>bcpio</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-bcpio</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>bin</extension>
        <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>bmp</extension>
        <mime-type>image/bmp</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>body</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>cdf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-cdf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>cer</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-x509-ca-cert</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>class</extension>
        <mime-type>application/java</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>cpio</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-cpio</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>csh</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-csh</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>dib</extension>
        <mime-type>image/bmp</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>doc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/msword</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>dtd</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xml-dtd</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>dv</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-dv</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>dvi</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-dvi</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eps</extension>
        <mime-type>application/postscript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>etx</extension>
        <mime-type>text/x-setext</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>exe</extension>
        <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gif</extension>
        <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gtar</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-gtar</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gz</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-gzip</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>hdf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-hdf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>hqx</extension>
        <mime-type>application/mac-binhex40</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>htc</extension>
        <mime-type>text/x-component</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>htm</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>hqx</extension>
       <mime-type>application/mac-binhex40</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ief</extension>
        <mime-type>image/ief</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jad</extension>
        <mime-type>text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <mime-type>application/java-archive</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>java</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jnlp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpe</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpeg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jsf</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jspf</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>kar</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-midi</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>latex</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-latex</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>m3u</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpegurl</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mac</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-macpaint</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>man</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-troff-man</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mathml</extension>
        <mime-type>application/mathml+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>me</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-troff-me</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mid</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-midi</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>midi</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-midi</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mif</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-mif</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mov</extension>
        <mime-type>video/quicktime</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>movie</extension>
        <mime-type>video/x-sgi-movie</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mp1</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mp2</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mp3</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mp4</extension>
        <mime-type>video/mp4</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mpa</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mpe</extension>
        <mime-type>video/mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mpeg</extension>
        <mime-type>video/mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mpega</extension>
        <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mpg</extension>
        <mime-type>video/mpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>mpv2</extension>
        <mime-type>video/mpeg2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ms</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-wais-source</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>nc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-netcdf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>oda</extension>
        <mime-type>application/oda</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Database -->
        <extension>odb</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Chart -->
        <extension>odc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Formula -->
        <extension>odf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Drawing -->
        <extension>odg</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Image -->
        <extension>odi</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Master Document -->
        <extension>odm</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Presentation -->
        <extension>odp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Spreadsheet -->
        <extension>ods</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Text -->
        <extension>odt</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Drawing Template -->
        <extension>otg </extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- HTML Document Template -->
        <extension>oth</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Presentation Template -->
        <extension>otp</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Spreadsheet Template -->
        <extension>ots</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template </mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <!-- OpenDocument Text Template -->
        <extension>ott</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <!-- xiph mime types -->

    ...

    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>wspolicy</extension>
        <mime-type>application/wspolicy+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>Z</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-compress</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>z</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-compress</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zip</extension>
        <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <!-- <welcome-file>index/stockPrices</welcome-file> -->
        <!-- <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
        <!-- <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> -->
        <!-- <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
        <!-- <welcome-file>admin.jsp</welcome-file> -->
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

The content of server.xml is pasted below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" />
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Now, from searching the internet, someone mentioned that I need to create symbolic link for my GWT application, but I am unsure if it is correct.

Should my SSL vhost look like below?

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost _default_:443>

      Protocols h2 http/1.1

      ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
      ServerName  www.zethanath.tk
      ServerAlias servlet.zethanath.tk zethanath.tk

      DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat/webapps/Index"

      Alias /Index "/opt/tomcat/webapps/Index"
      <Directory "/opt/tomcat/webapps/Index">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride NONE
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
      </Directory>

      <Location "/Index/WEB-INF/">
         AllowOverride None
         Deny from all
      </Location>

      JKMountCopy On
      JKMount /* ajp13_worker

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      SSLEngine on

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

      <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      </FilesMatch>
      <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
         SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
      </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Here is the content of "/etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties". workers.tomcat_home=/opt/tomcat
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
ps=/
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=ajp13_worker